# rolling back all changes when errors happen in ParallelFlux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I am using spring webflux with reactor and I have the following flux for uploading images, resizing them and storing them. For each size I execute the described flux in parallel on a custom executor service.

Any of the methods `createDbAttachmentEntity`, `resizeAttachment`, `storeFile` can throw various exceptions.

Executing the resizing in parallel means that any thread involved may throw exception. That means I need to rollback all the changes in case something was not properly executed.

For example I may have 5 sizes but in DB the system added only 4 and 5 are expected. Or I may have an error in converting my streams. Or I may have an error in the storage system.

In case of exception I would like to be able to rollback all the changes (manually delete database entries and manually delete the files.

How can I do that?

```
Flux.just(sizes)
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executorService))
        .map(size -> createDbAttachmentEntity(size))
        .map(size_attachment -> resizeAttachment(size_attachment.getT1(), originalBytes))
        .map(size_attachment_bytes -> storeFile(...))
        .sequential()
        .collectList()
        .map(list -> {
            if(list.size() != sizes.length
                    || list.stream().anyMatch(objects -> objects.getT2().getId() == null)) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            return list;
        })
        .flux()
  here  .onErrorReturn(.......deleteEntities...........deleteFiles...........)     // problem: I do not have the files/entities
        .flatMap(list -> Flux.fromStream(list.stream()))
        .collectMap(Tuple2::getT1, Tuple2::getT2);
```

I was thinking about solving it with this but it doesn't work

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
            .map(integer -> {
                if (integer == 3) throw new RuntimeException("3");
                return integer;
            })
            .flatMap(integer -> Flux.just(integer)
                    .onErrorResume(t -> {
                        System.out.println("--onErrorResume" + integer); // here is what I need to pass in
                        return Flux.empty();
                    }))
```

Comment: first of all, dont throw exceptions, return `Mono.error()` instead, exceptions are not functional. If it really needs to be parallel you can make use of the reactive context and place the entities in there, and retrieve them at a later stage in the chain.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf are you saying that I should have a `catch (throwable) {return Mono.error()}` for each function that I am calling? In my case the code can easily throw `InterruptedException`, `DataAccessException` or `IOException`.

Comment: He means instead of `if (integer == 3) throw new RuntimeException("3");` use `if (integer == 3) return Mono.error()`

Comment: Of course. But in the real scenario it still doesn't solve the problem because I can't control all possible errors

Comment: Also the problem in my second example is that onErrorResume is never called

Comment: @ThomasAndolf What difference do you think calling Mono.error(exception) makes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly could do something similar to this

Custom Exception:

```
public class FluxEntitiesException extends RuntimeException {

    private Set<Entity> entities;
    public FluxEntitiesException() {
        super();
    }
    public FluxEntitiesException(String s) {
        super(s);
    }
    public FluxEntitiesException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
    public FluxEntitiesException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public FluxEntitiesException(Set<Entity> entities) {
        super();
        this.entities = entities;
    }

    public Set<Entity> getEntities() {
        return entities;
    }

    static final long serialVersionUID = -1848914673093119416L;
}
```

Example processor:

```
public void processError(FluxEntitiesException e){
    for(Entity entity: e.entities){
        //DO SOMETHING TO ROLL BACK
        System.out.println("Rolling back: " + entity);
    }
}
```

Example entity:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Entity {
    private Integer id;
    //WHATEVER ELSE
}
```

Example Repo method:

```
public Entity addEntity(Entity entity) throws RuntimeException{
    if(entity.getId() >4)
        throw new RuntimeException("OH NO!");
    System.out.println("Added entity" + entity);
    return entity;
}
```

Example method:

```
public void AddToDb(){
    Set<Entity> entities = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<>());

    Flux.just(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
            //Parallel stuff isn't needed was just an example since you use it in original
            .parallel()
            .runOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .map(s -> addEntity(new Entity(s)))
            .doOnNext(entities::add)
            .sequential()
            .doOnError(e -> processError(new FluxEntitiesException(entities)))
            .collectList()
            .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(entities));
}
```

Comment: This may be a possible solution, I was thinking if it is possible to do this just using Reactor.

Comment: @tzortzik As ThomasAndolf said in the comments, it may be possible using the Subscriber context, but I'm pretty sure that's not what it's designed for, nor do I think the result will be very readable.

Comment: `I'm pretty sure that's not what it's designed for` then what is it designed for?

Comment: I legitimately can not remember how you said to use it, and all the comments seem to be gone, so not sure of the context. Possibly I was saying it's not designed to set values that will be then be used later in the chain, dependant on a previous publisher, since it passes the context up the chain not down.